# Cant run more than X Dags in parallel

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, airflow

I have created a DAG that runs without a problem with Sequential Executor and Local Executor. But, when I try to run the dag with catchup=True, I cant run more that 5 instances of this dag in parallel.
I have increased parallelism in the airflow.cgf file to 300 and concurrency and max_active_runs to 100 in my dag definition but still I get maximum of 5 parallel runs. In addition, when these 5 dag runs are done, the next 5 runs are not starting to run. Ideally, I would like to run X instances of the same dag per day (1 instance for each day that I have to catch up). Any help?

[image]

Comment: may I know how much is your concurrency?

Comment: @Rajalakshmi Thanks for the answer. As I mention already in my post, the concurency was set to 100